# Adding a form in SharePoint online

Tags: form

I'm using SharePoint online, set up by another company. There have been loads of issues with permissions and in general the whole build (of a simple intranet) has been pretty painful.

I need to add a basic form to a page to allow users to submit a question, which sends their entered content into a list which we'll collate manually. (There are likely to be lots of duplicate questions.)

I'm sure it shouldn't be so difficult! It's a plain text form, literally one textarea and a submit button, but I can't see any way to do it.

So, how do you add forms in Sharepoint? Is there a standard webpart which had been removed from our install for some reason? I've read lots of posts recommending using SharePoint designer, but it looks like if we edit the pages using that, then we can no longer edit the page through the browser.

I can see the option to edit or create forms in relation to lists, but no way of displaying these on the page.

So, how do you add forms?

Answer (score 0):

There are Out of the Box forms you can use that will meet your requirements (NewForm.aspx & EditForm.aspx) First, you would create a Content Type on your list. Make sure CTypes are enabled on your list  by navigating to List Settings => Advanced Settings => Enable Content Types. Then, you can add fields to your Content Type which is what will show on your form when a user clicks new item. For your situation add a 'Multiple Lines of Text' field to your new Content Type.

You can then send the user directly to the Form by copying the URL when you click 'New Item' on the list. When the user clicks 'Save', the Question will be stored in the List for your review. You can also setup notifications when a new List Item is added

Content Types in SharePoint online : [What are SharePoint Content Types? Learn How to Create and Use Them](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-content-types-understand-use-create)

Setting up Alerts in SharePoint Online : [Create an alert to get notified when a file or folder changes in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-SharePoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest possible way is to create a new custom list, adding whatever fields you want, and then providing a link on the page to the "newform.aspx" page for the list. Easy to set up, and all the data lands in a SharePoint list. Optionally, do what Colbs suggested and set up a content type, though that is an optional step that's probably not needed for your scenario.

If you're using SharePoint online, then you should have access to "Forms". Look on your app launcher (the grid button in the upper left). Forms allows you to build...forms. So, set up a form with whatever questions/fields you want. And then to share the form with users, you can either put a link to the form on the page, or you can copy an embed code and put the form directly on the page. To do this, after copying the embed code in Microsoft Forms for your form, go to your sharepoint page, and select to edit the page. Click your cursor in the section of the page where you want the form to go, and then click the "Edit Source" button up on the ribbon. (Note: the data that users enter winds up in an excel file, not a SharePoint list.)

Note: it's somewhat challenging to give step by step directions these days, as you might be working with the newer style "modern" pages, or the older style "classic(?)" pages. The instructions above are for classic mode.